# When exporting image from Sketch, why does the color slightly changes?

Tags: colors, xcode

If I configure an asset in Sketch with color #00EDC7 (for example), export it in PDF (or PNG):

[image]

Then I go in Xcode, then I create the image in the interface editor, create a view component, settings its background color to #00EDC7 => the color will be different that my exported image.

[image]

Then if I use the Xcode color picker and I pick the exported asset color, the color found will be #6CE8C8

[image]

Why? Color configuration? How to configure Sketch to avoid this?

Comment: ICC / colour profiles would be my first guess

Comment: Interesting. I tried to change Sketch color profiles to `Display P3`, the one Xcode uses, and now i'm having almost the same color. But instead #00EDC7, the generated asset has #6EEDC7! Very strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing in Xcode is your exported graphic (which appears to have an sRGB ICC profile) rendered in the Display P3 colorspace. The color appears darker in the graphic compared to using the same RGB numeric values because sRGB has a narrower color gamut. In other words, its range of values from 0-255 map to a subset of Display P3's values. Also note that conversions aren't necessarily linear. 0, 0, 0 in sRGB is going to convert to 0, 0, 0 in Display P3 while, obviously, the red and blue values from your color had to map differently to show the same perceptual color.

[image: colorsync utility screenshot]

I don't work in Sketch so I can't say whether it allows you to export a graphic with an ICC profile (sRGB, Display P3). However, in Xcode's custom color picker you can click on the settings icon and choose the color space in which you want to define a color:

[image: Xcode color picker color space]

This will at least allow you to match colors if your exporting application only supports sRGB. If you can export an asset as a 16-bit, Display P3 PNG or as a vector PDF with an embedded ICC profile, then you can work in Display P3 in both. In that case, you'd change the custom color picker's setting to Display P3.